# (Discord.py) Loading cogs and printing their status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, this is actually for revolt.chat's defectio python library, but they are very similar libraries and so I won't need help interpreting a response if it's directed towards discord.py.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to show the time it took to load a cog and while the cog is loading to go back and forth between "Loading administration cog.", "Loading administration cog.." and again with a third "." until it's finished and then ultimately ending up with {cogname} cog loaded in {x} seconds, for every cog which would be hard the way I have it now.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    sys.stdout.write("\rLoading 'Administration' cog.")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("\rLoading 'Administration' cog..")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r'Administration' cog loaded..!")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Preferably and also alternatively(as it's more advanced a question), I would like to be able to add this for loading each cog but I would like to once all cogs are loaded have "All cogs loaded in {x} seconds"

Comment: I think it can be big problem. Most code is loaded when you start script - and the same can be with Cog. Other think - `on_ready` can be execute when all code is already loaded so it is too late to measure time or display messages. And if you try to write someting without `\n` then you may have to use `flush()` after every `write()`.

Comment: If you use `add_cog()` then you could take `time` before `add_cog()` and after `add_cog()` to measure how long it takes. But to may need other thread to display text `Loading` at the same time. But discord may load it i.e. 1 second or 10 seconds - and you can't know this value - so it hard to say when to display next dot - after 0.5s or after 5 seconds. Maybe you should add new `.` every 1 second  and don't care how many dots you will get. Or you could disply animation using chars `\ `,  `|` `/`, `-`

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Surely, it has sent me in the right direction but do you think you could add a snippet of what said code might look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I mean I know its been 2 years but if anyone is looking for a solution for discord.py 2.0 I've found this to work. With a ping command in it as a test

```
import discord
import asyncio
import time 
import sys
from discord.ext import commands


class test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        cog_name = "PUT_CUSTOM_NAME_HERE"
        start_time = time.time()

        sys.stdout.write(f"\rloading '{cog_name}' cog.")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        for i in range(3):
            sys.stdout.write(f"\rloading '{cog_name}' cog{'.' * (i + 1)}")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
        end_time = time.time()
        loading_time = end_time - start_time 
        sys.stdout.write(f"\'{cog_name}' cog loaded in {loading_time:.2f} seconds")
        sys.stdout.flush()


    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(test(bot))
```